# How can multiple developers work on the same feature (branch)?

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch, workflow

Developer A is working on a feature in his local repository. Developer A is unfinished with his work, however he needs to transfer his work to Developer B so Developer B may continue the feature in his own local repository and later push to master. Working with Git in Microsoft Visual Studio, is there a workflow that exists that would allow this?

Answer (score 0):

If the branch is being taken over by another developer **and** you don't want (for whatever reason) the branch to show up on *any* repo until this is finished, they could exchange patch files (generated with `git format-patch`) so that developer B can create an equivalent of the work that Developer A had been doing.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

Comment: It is fine for it to show up on a repository before it is finished. Also, I asked if this is possible within Visual Studio. This did not answer my question.

Comment: This is an old thread but leaving a comment for anyone who needs an answer to - "If this is possible with Visual Studio/VS Code?". The answer is "Yes". Google search "git vs code".

Answer (score 0):

Use a feature branch which will be pushed to origin and can be used by multiple developers.
Once the feature is ready merge it to Master.
See: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow